# How to make sure my app only runs on devices with 7''+ screen size?

Tags: android, android-screen-support, android-screen

I want to make sure my app only runs in tablets with at least 7'' physical screen size.

I've read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps

And I have the following code in my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="13"/>
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

When I check the list of supported devices in the Google Play Console I see that devices with 5.3'' screens like [Samsung Galaxy Note](http://www.samsung.com/au/consumer/mobile-phone/mobile-phone/galaxy-note/GT-N7000ZBJXSA-spec) are still listed there.

Is there any way to make sure my app only runs on devices with at least 7'' physical screen size?

Comment: Why is this important to you? I mean, dp is better representation of what you may be able to fit onto the screen. Inches does not tell anything about resolution.

Comment: Because my UI doesn't work very well on a small screen.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to make sure my app only runs on devices with at least 7'' physical screen size?

Not at this time.

One hopes that, someday, the Play Store will honor `android:requiresSmallestWidthDp` as a filter. Technically, even that won't handle a 7" diagonal, though you can choose a `android:requiresSmallestWidthDp` value that should be big enough for likely aspect ratios.